# parse a column contains a path value in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

How I can parse a column that contains a URL path value in SQL Server?

The input

```
sites/System1/DocLib1/Folder1/SubFolder/File.pdf
```

should return:

```
Column 1 - Column 2 - Column 3- Column 4- Column 5 - Column 6
sites      System1    DocLib1   Folder1   SubFolder  File.pdf
```

path value is different for each row

Comment: Do you know ***exactly*** how many columns you want the result to ***always*** have?  SQL won't give differing numbers of columns based on the data.  Another important question is ***why*** would you want to do this?  There may be a better approach if we understand how you intend to make use of the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a known or max number of levels, you can use a little XML.

If unknown, you would have to go dynamic.

**Example**

```
Declare @yourtable table (id int,url varchar(500))
Insert Into @yourtable values
(1,'sites/System1/DocLib1/Folder1/SubFolder/File.pdf')

Select A.id
      ,B.*
 From  @yourtable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos8 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos9 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(url,'/','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
id  Pos1    Pos2    Pos3    Pos4    Pos5        Pos6        Pos7    Pos8    Pos9
1   sites   System1 DocLib1 Folder1 SubFolder   File.pdf    NULL    NULL    NULL
```